# Spatie Activity log_name not being set

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the following package:
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v4/introduction

I am able to perform everything perfectly, except set the "log_name" in the "activity_log" table. Regardless of my attempts, it's still setting to the default of "default". In this example I am trying to set it to "applications".

**Application.php**

```
use Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\LogsActivity;

use HasFactory, Notifiable, LogsActivity;

protected static $logName = 'applications';
protected static $logAttributes = ['*'];
protected static $logOnlyDirty = true;
protected static $logAttributesToIgnore = ['updated_at', 'survey_key'];
protected static $recordEvents = ['updated', 'deleted'];
```

**and my ApplicationController.php**

```
activity()
   ->causedBy(Auth::user()->id)
   ->performedOn($app)
   ->withProperties([
      'employers' => $request->employers
   ])
   ->log('Nudge sent to ' . count($request->employers) . ' Employers.');
```

**I have also tried with the getActivitylogOptions:**

```
public function getActivitylogOptions()
{
    return \LogOptions::defaults()
        ->useLogName('applications')
        ->logAttributes(['*'])
        ->logOnlyDirty(true)
        ->logAttributesToIgnore(['updated_at', 'survey_key'])
        ->recordEvents(['deleted'])
        ->setDescriptionForEvent(fn(string $eventName) => "Application has been {$eventName}")
        ->dontLogIfAttributesChangedOnly(['text']);
}
```

Comment: Try this `->useLog('log_name')` it will work

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it by:

```
activity('applications')
    ->causedBy(Auth::user()->id)
    ->performedOn($app)
    ->withProperties([
        'employers' => $request->employers
    ])
    ->log('Nudge sent to ' . count($request->employers) . ' Employers.');
```